# Why is my JavaScript function apparently not being called?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

This JavaScript function used to work before until I made it more complicated as I try to push more error checking to the front end.

Here is the front end code just the important bits for brevity:

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
     <script type = "text/javascript" >
         function checkThings()
         {
             var jobSeekerFirstName = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerFirstName')[0].value
             var jobSeekerLastName = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerLastName')[0].value
             var jobSeekerUserName = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerUserName')[0].value
             var jobSeekerPassword = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerPassword')[0].value
             var jobSeekerPhoneNumber = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerPhoneNumber')[0].value
             var jobSeekerEmail = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekerEmailAddress')[0].value
             var jobSeekerAnswer = document.getElementsByName('txtJobSeekersSecurityAnswer')[0].value
             if ((jobSeekerFirstName != '') && (jobSeekerLastName != '') && (jobSeekerUserName != '') &&
                 (jobSeekerPassword != '') && (jobSeekerPhoneNumber != '') && (jobSeekerEmail != '') &&
                 (jobSeekerAnswer != '')) // First check all fields entered
             {
                 if (jobSeekerUserName.length == 6) {
                     var emAddrCounter;
                     var emlength = jobSeekerEmail.length;
                     var emailCorrect = false;
                     for (emAddrCounter = 0; ((emAddrCounter < emlength) && (emailCorrect == false)) ; emAddrCounter++) {
                         var emChar = jobSeekerEmail.charAt(emAddrCounter);
                         if (emChar == '@') emailCorrect = true;
                     }
                     if (emailCorrect == false) {
                         var emailNoAtChar = " Email address must contain @ character. Please reenter";
                         document.getElementsById('txtMessageBox').Text = emailNoAtChar;
                         return false;
                     }
                     else {
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     var userNameNotSix = " User name must be exactly six characters long. Please reenter";
                     document.getElementsByName('txtMessageBox').Text = userNameNotSix;
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 var allElementsPresent = " All Fields must be filled in first. Please reenter all fields";
                 document.getElementsById('txtMessageBox').Text = allElementsPresent;
                 return false;
             }
         }
    </script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scripman1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

calling line

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnNewJobSeekerRegistration" runat="server" 
             Text=" Register me as a new Job Seeker " 
             OnClientClick= "return checkThings();"
             OnClick="btnNewJobSeekerRegistration_Click" />
```

I keep getting

> Operation Completed

and it seems to have skipped all the JavaScript function and all the error checking therein. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your html code also to better understand

Comment: its probably because you have some error on the javascript and after the error is thrown the button continue the post back and you miss it... open the console on your browser to see what the error is

Comment: Your JavaScript is full of errors. Try debugging it without a asp.net button so there will be no PostBack.

Comment: @VDWWD Your JavaScript is full of errors does not tell me what those errors are. Can you specify one error you see there. How do I debug it without the asp.net button?? My idea is that it is not being called at all rather than having errors. I will look over it.

Comment: The only "errors" I see are that the var statements in javascript have not being terminated with this symbol ";" I went back in and terminated them correctly still the same behaviour the function is not being called and it is going straight into the back end codebehind function to execute it without executing the JavaScript. Weird one I think.

Comment: Thank you Aristos or should I say Charalampos Mavridis. "Probably" because I have some error!! What is the error??? It is not telling me I have any error but just going straight to execute the code behind backend code. If it told me the error I would fix it but it does not tell me anything.

Comment: Thank you Nitin Kumar. I have posted the full front end code in an answer below. Maybe the JavaScript function does not return a value I am guessing, or it is not at all being called one or the other.

Comment: I removed useless text

Comment: Thank you Aristos: Here is the error in the console JobSeekerRegistration.aspx:100 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function. I changed the function from document.getElementsById to document.getElementsByName and it now works.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When your JavaScript code is "not being called" it is usually because there is something wrong with it. When any line of the JavaScript throws an exception, and remember this JavaScript code is not compiled but interpreted and executed immediately at runtime, I am guessing every bit of code below it is simply skipped and the codebehind in the back end is automatically executed. To debug it you need to open the developer's console in your browser's debugger. For me this was Chrome, so go to: Customise and Control Google Chrome/More tools/Developer tools (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>), then go to Console. Now run your code from within Visual Studio and observe what exception or error is thrown from within the JavaScript code. For me this error was "JobSeekerRegistration.aspx:100 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function". All I did then was change the document.getElementsById in two lines of my code to document.getElementsByName and voila it worked. A special thank you to Aristos but my answer is the best.